# What it means /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter?

Tags: linux, cron

I create start.sh file and wont to start,but retruned me

```
./start.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

this is my start.sh file content

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/test/Desktop
node cron.js
```

How can I fixed this problem?

Comment: Allow us to Google that for you: [/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Fbin%2Fbash^M%3A+bad+interpreter+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your script file has MSWin line endings. Use `dos2unix` or `fromdos` to fix them.

Comment: How can I fixed problem?

Comment: Do you have `dos2unix` or `fromdos` installed?

Comment: I instaled fromdos,but dont know how to use.

Comment: See `man fromdos` to see the manual page.